# Wetransfer with Thunderbird on Ubuntu [Solved]

Tags: thunderbird, filelink

Thunderbird 60.5 supports Wetransfer for large attachments via the Filelink feature. Configuring Wetransfer was pretty straight forward under Win10, but I cannot configure it under Ubuntu.

Is Wetransfer for Thunnderbird FileLink supported under Ubuntu, and if yes, how can i enable it?

I'm running Thunderbird 60.6.1 (form the main repo) on Ubuntu 18.04.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For reference, I've just upgraded to 60.9.0 on my Ubuntu 18.04 install from the standard repositories, and the FileLink extension now is included by default.

Comment: Yes, after upgrading to 60.9.0, I could add Wetransfer to FileLink. Thanks for the heads up!